# Excel: Applying structural changes from a master workbook to other workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out a way to make other excel workbooks match the structure of a master workbook after making changes to the master version.

The other workbooks are translated versions of the master workbook, and should always have the same structure as the master.  I need to be able to add, remove, change, or reorder rows in the master workbook, and then apply the structural changes to all of the translated workbooks, and have the added and changed rows flagged to be retranslated.  I would like to do this automatically instead of manually editing each workbook each time there is a change.

I can index the rows in the master workbook, but I haven't been able to work out if it's possible to apply this to another work book.  Below is an example of what the order of the master may be after it has been changed.

```
Index | Master Text | Change 
------|-------------|-------
1     |Line 1       |
5     |Line 5       |
6     |Line 6       |
2     |Line 2       |remove
      |new line     |add
3     |Line 3x      |change
```

And the expected outcome of the translated workbook:

```
| Transl Text | Change | ReTranslate
|-------------|--------|-----
|Line 1       |        |
|Line 5       |        |
|Line 6       |        |
|new line     |add     |   Y
|Line 3x      |change  |   Y
```

A few things:

- There are approximately 30 sheets in the master workbook (and therefore each of the language versions).  Changes can occur anywhere in the workbook.
- There are about 20 language versions of the workbook.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: What have you researched so far [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a code writing service but a Q&A place for problems/errors with code.